# STM32CubeIDE: How to disable auto re-generation the code when .ioc saved

Tags: stm32cubeide

I have checked the "Remember my answer" for re-generating code after saving the .ioc file. How can I disable it now?

Comment: If you make a chance in .ioc, wouldn't you want it to take effect? I mean, if you don't generate code again, the changes won't be applied at all. And auto-generated code doesn't affect your own code, it will be preserved. My point being, are you trying to solve a problem that actually needs solving? Is there some problem with it to begin with? Just trying to understand your reasoning for it, maybe there is a better way to do things than that.

Comment: @Ilya In my case, I do not necessarily keep the .ico file updated and I use a different file/folder structure than the auto-generated code. All in all, I need to do some merging and cleanup after the code generation so I do not always want to generate code after making an update to the .ioc file.

Comment: @Ilya Some changes doesn't required the code generation at moment. For example `Backup previously generated files when re-generating`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want STM32CubeIDE to forget the "remember my decision" choice about re-generating code.

I do not know if there is a way to do this in the GUI. The only solution I found (after a considerable amount of investigation) is to edit the following file under the workspace directory (it is probably a good idea to close STM32CubeIDE while doing this):

```
   <WORKSPACE_FOLDER>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.st.stm32cube.c
ommon.preferences.prefs
```

The file should have a line saying

```
DeviceConfigurationTool.AskToDoCodeGenerationOnIocSave=false
```

Remove that line and you should start getting the question about generating code again after saving the .ioc file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in GUI too. Go to:

```
Window >> Preferences >> STM32Cube >> Device Configuration
```

And look under "Code Generation Persistent Choices"

:)